# Python any of many dependencies

Tags: python, dependency-management, setuptools

From time to time I come across a situation where I have a package that can depend on either package A or B.

For example, my project depends on a package called `spam`, if this project is renamed to `pyspam`, my project can either depend on `spam` or `pyspam`.

I cannot figure out (or find) how I would define such dependencies in setup.py. What is a commonly accepted way to solve this?

EDIT: I would like to define the dependencies in `setup.py`. Something like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='myproject',
    install_requires=[
        'spam || pyspam'
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check to see if the package is available, and decide which to use based on that. (I hope I understood your question correctly).

```
from setuptools import setup

imp_spam = "spam"
try:
    import spam
except:
    imp_spam = "pyspam"

setup(
    name='myproject',
    install_requires=[imp_spam]
)
```

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for. If neither package is installed, `pyspam` is installed in your example. There is unfortunately no handling of scenarios where either package might not exist (remotely). In such a case a dependency may serve as a fallback. This answer will probably work in most cases, so +1.

Comment: Well, you have to define one of them as a preferred one, right? Just reverse the order to make the other one preferred in case both are missing.

Comment: If a package does not (yet) exists on a pypi server, the install fails. Instead it should try to fetch the other package as it also satisfies the dependency.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. My answer is not complete then. Not sure how to achieve that though...

Answer (score -3):

```
try:
    import ham
except ImportError:
    import spam
```