# How to tell setuptools I want one library in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

My program supports many libraries (`pylibmc` or `memcache`), but requires at least one of them to be installed to work.

How can I declare this to setuptools?

It would be nice if I could give an order of preference (ie. tell pip which one to install if none of them is available)

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27486589/python-any-of-many-dependencies

Comment: @cel: I don't like the answers there.  They look incomplete to me.

Comment: @Kevin, well it seems that this feature is not implemented (yet?). So I guess the best we can expect is a dirty workaround hack.