# Why isn't `site.main()` called by setuptools?

Tags: pip, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, pep517

My code can use any Qt binding. I try to reduce the number of packages to install. For that, I'd like to check whether a package has already been installed and report it as the sole requirement. If nothing's installed, I pick the first item on the list.

```py
# cat setup.py

from typing import NamedTuple

from setuptools import setup

class PackageRequirement(NamedTuple):
    package_name: str
    import_name: str

def is_package_importable(package_requirement: PackageRequirement) -> bool:
    try:
        __import__(package_requirement.import_name)
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def required_package() -> str:
    qt_list = [
        PackageRequirement(package_name='PySide6', import_name='PySide6.QtCore'),
        PackageRequirement(package_name='PyQt6', import_name='PyQt6.QtCore'),
        PackageRequirement(package_name='PyQt5', import_name='PyQt5.QtCore'),
        PackageRequirement(package_name='PySide2', import_name='PySide2.QtCore'),
    ]
    for p in qt_list:
        if is_package_importable(p):
            return p.package_name
    return qt_list[0].package_name

setup(install_requires=[required_package()])
```

The code resembles [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27487021/8554611). However, despite `pip freeze` reports that I have `PyQt5` installed in the `venv`, and I can import it manually, the code reports the opposite and installs `PySide6`.

I run the code in a `venv` virtual environment as

```
pip install package_name.tar.gz
```

I've tried

```py
from importlib.metadata import version, PackageNotFoundError

try:
    version(package_requirement.package_name)
except PackageNotFoundError:
    return False
else:
    return True
```

instead of

```py
try:
    __import__(package_requirement.import_name)
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    return False
else:
    return True
```

with the same result. It looks like either the code ignores site-packages, or the access to them is somehow blocked.

Indeed, as soon as I prepend the code with

```py
import site

site.main()  # the line might be redundant
```

the packages are tested correctly.

---

By the way, are there any tricks to achieve the package selection more gracefully and in a `wheel` package?

Comment: I am not sure I understand why your `setup.py` does what it does. It seems strange to me. Is all this complexity really necessary? -- Is this how other Qt-based libraries handle this?

Comment: @sinoroc, they don't. They just crash when they can import nothing. I wish there was a way to make it easier. I couldn't find any PEP covering the problem, and I don't have months to implement one. `setuptools`  are unlikely to go above and beyond the PEPs, although I hope they watch SO.

Comment: I do not know much about the reasons why your project is built like it is, but from what I understood out of this question, I think that if I were you I would make all dependencies to Qt bindings optional. In other words I would list these dependencies as *extra*s. And the user doing the installation could choose an extra in order to select a Qt binding dependency. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @sinoroc, I've thought about it. However, for Windows users (they tend to be the least competent), it's too complicated to find out what Qt binding is installed and is installable. I _have_ to rely on the automatic discovery of Qt packages. BTW, thanks for fixing the tags!

Comment: I see. It is always a game of balancing between user friendliness and flexibility. -- I believe the solution with extras I suggested is the most correct considering what the current state of Python packaging is. -- ***1.*** If a set of Qt bindings is already installed the user should install without extras. ***2.*** If user has no bindings and does not specify extra, then library should fail gracefully with message saying that bindings need to be installed. ***3.*** Documentation of the library should be very clear to explain how to use extras (it is not that hard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, in order to install a dependency from source code or from *sdist*, *pip* first builds this dependency into a *wheel*, and this build step is made in an ephemeral isolated build environment. So this isolated build environment has its own `site-packages`, and the other dependencies can not be imported.

What you could try is to [deactivate the "*build isolation*"](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-no-build-isolation) when installing that dependency. Try to take some time to understand the possible side effects, also maybe try to use this option only for that dependency and not for its dependencies.

```
python -m pip install --no-build-isolation --no-deps package_name.tar.gz
```

Comment: This indeed does the trick! Thanks! However, the command line key is far from obvious. I wish there was a way to implement it in `pyproject.toml`. Unfortunately, The developers are clearly against the usage of non-isolated environments.

Comment: And no, the environment appears to be the same, not a new one with its own `site-packages`. It's just that the `site-packages` are not available, not listed. Otherwise, how could `import site` resolve the issue?

Comment: I do not know what happens when you do `import site` in a build environment, I never looked into this, and I never saw anything about this. And now I am curious, feel free to ask about it [here](https://discuss.python.org/c/packaging/14). -- The preferred process is to install from a *wheel*, and wheels do not contain the `setup.py`, there are good reasons why the process is designed like this, and yes there are some drawbacks too of course like anything else.

Comment: I've asked for a good alternative first: https://discuss.python.org/t/require-any-of-several-alternative-package-dependencies/26293. I'd prefer it to become a standard for a `wheel` package rather than digging into such dirty hacks.